# IBM Process Designer 8.5.6 GUI Language

Tags: process, designer

Since IBM Process Designer is eclipse based, ¿Is there a way to change the user interface language to other than english (i.e. Spanish)?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the way to change the GUI Language for Process Center, taking the following steps:

1. Open Process Center's URL (something like https://[server ip]:9444/ProcessCenter/login.jsp) and then login with your user/password
2. Open "Preferences"and then in "User Preferences" dialog select the new language you want to set.
3. Logout from Process Center
4. Opened Process Designer and the interface shows the newly selected language (the same happens with Process Center web page)

Hope this helps someone else.